# Exporting all data from Kendo Grid datasource

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I followed that tutorial about exporting Kendo Grid Data : http://www.kendoui.com/blogs/teamblog/posts/13-03-12/exporting_the_kendo_ui_grid_data_to_excel.aspx

Now I´m trying to export all data (not only the showed page) ... How can I do that?

I tried change the pagezise before get the data:

```
grid.dataSource.pageSize(grid.dataSource.total());
```

But with that my actual grid refresh with new pageSize. Is that a way to query kendo datasource without refresh the grid?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A better solution is to generate an Excel file from the real data, not from the dataSource.

1]
In the html page, add

```
$('#export').click(function () {
    var title = "EmployeeData";
    var id = guid();
    var filter = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource._filter;

    var data = {
        filter: filter,
        title: title,
        guid: id
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Employee/Export',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (result) {
            window.location = kendo.format("{0}?title={1}&guid={2}", '/Employee/GetGeneratedExcel', title, id);
        }
    });
});
```

2]
Add a method "Export" to the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Export(KendoGridFilter filter, string guid)
{
    var gridRequest = new KendoGridRequest();
    if (filter != null)
    {
        gridRequest.FilterObjectWrapper = filter.Filters != null ? filter.ToFilterObjectWrapper() : null;
        gridRequest.Logic = filter.Logic;
    }

    var query = GetQueryable().AsNoTracking();
    var results = query.FilterBy<Employee, EmployeeVM>(gridRequest);

    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var excel = new ExcelPackage(stream))
        {
            excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Employees");
            var ws = excel.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
            ws.Cells.LoadFromCollection(results);
            ws.Cells.AutoFitColumns();

            excel.Save();
            Session[guid] = stream.ToArray();
            return Json(new { success = true });
        }
    }
}
```

3]
Also add the method "GetGeneratedExcel" to the controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public FileResult GetGeneratedExcel(string title, string guid)
{
    // Is there a spreadsheet stored in session?
    if (Session[guid] == null)
    {
        throw new Exception(string.Format("{0} not found", title));
    }

    // Get the spreadsheet from session.
    var file = Session[guid] as byte[];
    string filename = string.Format("{0}.xlsx", title);

    // Remove the spreadsheet from session.
    Session.Remove(title);

    // Return the spreadsheet.
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", filename));
    return File(file, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", filename);
}
```

Also see this project on [github](https://github.com/StefH/KendoGridBinderEx/blob/master/KendoGridBinderEx.Examples.MVC).

See [this](http://kendogridbinderex.azurewebsites.net/Employee) live example project where you can export the Employees to Excel. (Although this returns filtered data, but you can modify the code to ignore the kendo grid filter and always return all data.

Comment: Thanks for the help... Doing that, I have to create a method export in all my controllers (100+). Today I have one Controller Export and a partial view to render the button export where I need .

Comment: hi @Stef, 
It works fine on IE but on Chrome it saves as "title.xlsx, attachement" file, can you fix it?

Comment: Please create an issue in github for this project : https://github.com/StefH/KendoGridBinderEx

Answer (score 1):

Really **old question** but:

To export all the pages use [`excel.allPages`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-excel.allPages):

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    toolbar: ["excel"],
    excel: {
        allPages: true
    },
    // ....
});
```

[See Example](http://dojo.telerik.com/Ufaro)

Comment: Any idea how to set `allPages: true` in a template-style grid?

Answer (score -2):

Grid toolbar

```
..
.ToolBar(toolbar =>
    {
        toolbar.Template(
            @<text>
                @Html.Kendo().Button().Name("grid-export").HtmlAttributes(new { type = "button", data_url = @Url.Action("Export") }).Content("Export").Events(ev => ev.Click("exportGrid"))
            </text>);
    })
..
```

Endpoint export function

```
public FileResult Export([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            DemoEntities db = new DemoEntities();
            byte[] bytes = WriteExcel(db.Table.ToDataSourceResult(request).Data, new string[] { "Id", "Name" });

            return File(bytes,
                "application/vnd.ms-excel",
                "GridExcelExport.xls");
        }
```

a javascript function to generate grid remote export url with all specified parameters

```
function exportGrid() {
    var toolbar = $(this.element);
    var gridSelector = toolbar.closest(".k-grid");
    var grid = $(gridSelector).data("kendoGrid");
    var url = toolbar.data("url");

    var requestObject = (new kendo.data.transports["aspnetmvc-server"]({ prefix: "" }))
        .options.parameterMap({
            page: grid.dataSource.page(),
            sort: grid.dataSource.sort(),
            filter: grid.dataSource.filter()
        });

    url = url + "?" + $.param({
        "page": requestObject.page || '~',
        "sort": requestObject.sort || '~',
        "pageSize": grid.dataSource.pageSize(),
        "filter": requestObject.filter || '~',
    });
    window.open(url, '_blank');
}
```

For detailed solution see my sample project on [Github](https://github.com/tareknaj/kendo-grid-export-excel)

where u can export grid server side with current configuration (sorting, filtering, paging) using helper function

Comment: @AlvaroAV done with including the essential parts here