# Exporting data to excel in Asp.Net MVC using Kendo Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, excel, telerik, kendo-grid, export-to-excel

I am using Kendo Grid and using the methods suggested in this [Article](http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/export-grid-to-excel) by Kendo. I am more interested towards the first approach as I find it faster than the 2nd approach.

The problem is if the number of records 65535, then it throws error
`Invalid Row number (65536) outside allowable range (0..65535)`

I am not able to find any solution to this. Done lot of research, tried the other method but that seems way too slow for my clients liking.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21120909/exporting-all-data-from-kendo-grid-datasource

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check if the row numbers are greater than 65535, if they are then you need to split the data in multiple sheets like so...

```
//create new workbook
var workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();

//create sheet
var sheet = workbook.CreateSheet();

//declare row number
int numberOfRow = 1;

//add value to sheet name inorder not to receive error that the sheet name already exists
int i = 0;

if(numberOfRow > 65535)
{
   sheet = workbook.CreateSheet("(Name of sheet " + ++i + ")");
   numberOfRow = 1; 

//include your header row here
}
```