# How to get the full URL from a Kendo UI DataSource?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I'm using Kendo UI Grid in my Javascript project. And I need to export my data in excel format, and what I need is getting the same URL which is made by dataSource object and add **?format=excel** to it.
Sometimes I must export to excel without the grid at all so I want to use the DataSource object to generate the URL and avoiding build it in kendo way manually.

But the problem is that I'm not able to get the full URL with sort and filter params from dataSource object.

Comment: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/excel-export current export functionality works with filtered and sorted data

Comment: I work in a system where the the export should be from the server side

Comment: And sometimes I just use the dataSource to build the url without using the grid at all.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21121406/1849455

Comment: Isn't there a way to just get the final URL from the dataSource object???

Comment: I need to get the url myself, so that I can kick it out of the cache after a certain period.

Comment: @TarekNajem Please do not make assumptions as to the intended solution. You have not supplied an answer specifically indicating how to retrieve the URL from the Kendo datasource object, which is often needed for custom export implementations (large data-sets being the primary reason).

Comment: @Arctic check my detailed answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/31230715/1849455